# change in dropdown list value not picked up in jquery validation

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build some validation into my web app and am having a small issue. I have an asp dropdown list and a textbox and want to make the textbox mandatory if someone selects 'Other' from the dropdown list. The validation works when I select Other but if I decide to select another option and click the save button, it still asks me to enter a value in the text box even though the selected value of the dropdown is not Other.

Here is my jquery function:

```
$(function() {

    $("#btnMainSave").click(function() {

        val = $('#ddlRefTo').val();
        alert(val);
        $("#form1").validate({

            rules: {

                txbRefToOther: val == "Other" ? "required" : "notrequired",
                txbRefConcern: "required"

            },
            messages: {
                txbRefConcern: "*This field is mandatory",
                txbRefToOther: "*This field is mandatory"

            },

            ignore: ""
        });
    });
});
```

The alert shows that the change in value is being picked up but for some reason, the validation part still insists that I put a value in the textbox even though val=something different to 'Other'.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

### Update

I've played around with custom validation and am still having some issues. Here is my custom validation method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("Test", function(value, element) {

        var val = $('#ddlRefTo').val();

        if (value.length==0 && val=="Other") {

            //INVALID
            return false;
        }
        // VALID
        else return true;
    },
             "*This field is required.");
```

and I'm referring to it like this:

```
$("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            txbRefToOther: {
                required: true,
                Test: true

            }
        }
    });
```

however as soon as I submit, the validation error is triggered no matter what is selected in the dropdown and only stops when I enter something in the textbox.

However, if I set the validation on the dropdown instead of the textbox as follows:

```
$.validator.addMethod("Test", function(value, element) {

  if (value=="Other" && $('#txbRefToOther').val()=="") {

              //INVALID
               return false; 
           }
           // VALID
          else return true; 
            },
             "*This field is required.");

$("#form1").validate({
          rules: {
                ddlRefTo:{
                            required: true,
                           Test: true

                        }
                    }
        });
```

it works the way I want it to but the error message appears with the dropdown list instead! Why doesnt the first version work? Heres my HTML if it helps:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
......
......
<table width="530">
<tr>
<td class="Label" width="80">Referring to</td>
<td width="120"><asp:DropDownList id="ddlRefTo" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Font-Size="9pt" Width="110">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Test1" Value="Test1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Test2" Value="Test2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Test3" Value="Test3"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="Other"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

</td>
<td class="Label" align="right" width="170">If 'Other', Please specify</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txbRefToOther" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Width="150"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>
</table>
<asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Click" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the message to the required validation only:

```
messages:{
    txtRefToOther:{
        required: "*This field is mandatory"
    }
```

Also, what is notrequired? Make sure you have that defined as a custom method.

---

Based on your comments, I think your best bet is to add a custom method to handle this validation. Here's the custom method:

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("conditionallyRequired", function (value, element, params) {
    if ($("'#" + params + "'").val() == "Other") && value == ''{
         return false; //INVALID
    }
    return true; // VALID
}, "*This field is required." //VALIDATION MESSAGE      
);

// connect it to a css class 
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
    conditionallyRequired: { conditionallyRequired: true }
});
```

This method will check if ddlRefTo is 'Other' and if this textbox is blank. If yes, it will return false - invalid.
Apply the method to your textbox:

```
txtRefToOther:
{
    conditionallyRequired: ddlRefTo
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried as you suggested but unfortunately it hasn't solved my issue. I suppose I could re-write the function to do the check before calling validate and have separate function which validates the rest of the fields that don't reply on other criteria.

Comment: What is 'notrequired'? is that a custom method? can you post the code?

Comment: 'notrequired' isnt a method, its the false part of the logic but I don't know what the opposite keyword would be to 'required'. I've replaced it with "" to see if it made any difference but it hasn't. I'm still learning jquery but slowly getting there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried your method and I know in theory it should work but for some reason its not. I've even created a test page with just the dropdown and textbox and still no luck. However, If change it the other way round, ie place the validation on the dropdown list and check the textbox, it works! (but the error message appears next the the dropdown)

Comment: You need to take out required: true from the textbox validation. This will make it required regardless of what is in the dropdown. (I am commenting here because I do not have enough rep to comment on your question...)

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. It seems to have worked for the dropdown list. Now I'm doing the same issue with radio button lists but hopefully it will be much easier. Thanks again for all your help.